# Share same plot area and map to original xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some dataframes that I'd like to plot the information into the same area. The first data frame uses hue and plots some bars, and subsequently all plots in the same axis should map to those xticks (they might not be in the same order). See this example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "col" : ["col_a", "col_a", "col_a", "col_c", "col_c", "col_b", "col_b"], "cluster": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C"], "value_x":[2,4,1,5,6,2,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ "col" : ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"], "value_y": [11,13,9]})

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15, 5))

# This will write the "master order" of the xticks
sns.barplot(x="col", y="value_x", hue="cluster", data=df1, ax=ax)

# Follow plots in the same plot should map to those xticks
ax = sns.lineplot(
    data=df2,
    x="col",
    y="value_y",
    ax=ax,
)
```

The second line will not map correctly to the xticks. I was thinking in getting all the labels from the initial plot using "get_xticklabels" and using that as the master to join all subsequent frames so that when I plot them the order matches, but I was hoping there might be a better solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that `sns.barplot` is plotting the values of `df1`. First it finds `"col_a"` than `"col_c"` and finally `"col_b"`. Then you plot the line, where it finds `"col_a"`, `"col_b"` and `"col_c"`.

All you need to do is to sort the `df1` before plotting:

```
sns.barplot(x="col", y="value_x", hue="cluster", data=df1.sort_values(by=['col']), ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a possible custom sort of the initial data frame, based on some criteria. If that criteria is not replicable in the second data frame (for example the data might not be there), is there a general way of matching the original axes?

Comment: Let's say that `df1` contains all the necessary data, while `df2` has some missing data. Then, you can extract the ticks used to plot `df1` with `ax.get_xticks()` (in this example, it returns `array([0, 1, 2])`. At this point, you know that they represents `"col_a", "col_b", "col_c"`, respectively. So you can use `ax.plot` to plot the second line, where you map your x values to 0, 1, 2. With that you should be able to "align" the axis.